# How to Pass a Dropdown value in Angular to a Function?

Tags: angular

I have a dropdown value that is correctly displayed in the UI with the below:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="ccodeSelect" (ngModelChange)="ccodeSelect($event)">
  <option type="number" value=0>--Select a Company Code--</option>
  <option type="number" *ngFor="let dropdown of listDropdown" [value]="dropdown.Ccode">{{dropdown.Ccode}}</option>
  </select>
```

It is as well correctly displayed in my visual selection below:

```
<h6>Company Code: {{ccodeSelect}}</h6>
```

My question is how to make sure the dropdown value is taken in my function when I click Submit?
This is my submit button function:

```
createBilling(billing: Billing) {
return this.httpconnect.post(`${this.PATH}/billing`,billing);}
```

I need to basically replace the value in my function for ccode by the dropdown value

I am adding my Interface too where you can see the ccode value I am trying to replace:

```
 export interface Billing {
id?: number;
ccode?: number;
customer?: number;
```

};

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use (change) event instead of (ngModelChange).

in HTML:

```
     <select
        #mySelect
        (change)='onOptionChange(mySelect.value)'>
         <option *ngFor="let dropdown of listDropdown" 
           [value]="dropdown.Ccode">{{dropdown.Ccode}}
         </option>
    </select>
```

in TypeScript:

```
    onOptionChange(value:string){
     // you will get value here
     console.log("value is :: ", value);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for trying Sanjay - below reply from dom.macs worked for me

Comment: Glad to know. Have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the ngModelChange in your html.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="ccodeSelect">
  <option type="number" value=0>--Select a Company Code--</option>
  <option type="number" *ngFor="let dropdown of listDropdown" [value]="dropdown.Ccode">{{dropdown.Ccode}}</option>
</select>
```

Then update your submit function to assign the value of ccodeSelect to your billing object.

```
createBilling(billing: Billing) {
    billing.ccode = this.ccodeSelect;
    return this.httpconnect.post(`${this.PATH}/billing`, billing);
}
```

Comment: Thank you - so if I understand correctly I should add it to my source billing.service.ts file where my function is stored? I did that and imported my ts component where the value ccodeSelect is. It shows me the below error still: "Property ccodeSelect does not exist in billing service" I have added a constructor as well for my ts component .

Comment: Did you instantiate the billing object? You can add it in your constructor or in your ngOnInit.
this.billing = new Billing();

Comment: thanks so much - I have added it to the instantiation rather than the source and it worked. Appreciate it ! Super star! :)

Answer (score 0):

**billing.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    ...
})
export class BillingComponent {
  ...
  billing: Billing = {};
    
  ...
    
  createBilling() {
    console.log(this.billing);
    return this.httpconnect.post(`${this.PATH}/billing`, this.billing);
  }
    
}
```

**billing.component.html**

```
<select [(ngModel)]="billing.ccode">
  <option type="number" value="0">--Select a Company Code--</option>
  <option type="number" *ngFor="let dropdown of listDropdown" [value]="dropdown.Ccode">
    {{dropdown.Ccode}}
  </option>
</select>

<button (click)="createBilling()">Create Billing</button>
```